# Can I add easing to this?

Tags: jquery

I have a sliding section set up as below. I was wondering if I can somehow add `easeIn` and `easeOut` when the slide goes up and down.

```
$('a#slide-up').click(function () {
    $('.slide-container').slideUp(400, function(){
        $('#slide-toggle').removeClass('active');
    });
    return false;
});

$('a#slide-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var slideToggle = this;
    if ($('.slide-container').is(':visible')) {
        $('.slide-container').slideUp(400,function() {
            $(slideToggle).removeClass('active');
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.slide-container').slideDown(400);
        $(slideToggle).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Read this http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Please check the documentation of [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) at jQuery docs;.

By default jQUery implements only linear and swing easing functions. For additional easing functions you have to user jQUery UI

---

UPDATE:

Acoording to the doc, the second optional argument is a string indicating the name of the easing function.

So,

```
$('.slide-container').slideUp(400, function(){
        $('#slide-toggle').removeClass('active');
    });
```

will become

```
$('.slide-container').slideUp(400,'linear', function(){
        $('#slide-toggle').removeClass('active');
    });
```

to use linear easing function.

Similarly , for other easing functions also.

Comment: I checked the docs but am still unsure how to implement it. I do have jQuery UI added. Do you think you can show me where to implement easeIn and easeOut?

Comment: Thanks. For the line after `else`, do I have to do something like this? `$('.slide-container').slideDown(400,'linear','');` since there is no function?

Comment: @John, you can leave that, since it is optional. ie,  $('.slide-container').slideDown(400,'linear'); will be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

for *slideUp* and *slideDown* you ca add the easing effect:

```
$(".slide-container").slideUp({
    duration:500,
    easing:"easeOutExpo",
    complete:function(){
         $(slideToggle).removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You sure can, make sure you include the jQuery UI script as you do you regular jQuery library and add in the easing parameter to the [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) function.

Like so...

```
$('a#slide-up').click(function () {
    $('.slide-container').slideUp(400,'easeIn', function(){
    $('#slide-toggle').removeClass('active');
});
 return false;
});

$('a#slide-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

var slideToggle = this;
if ($('.slide-container').is(':visible')) {
    $('.slide-container').slideUp(400,'easeOut',function() {
        $(slideToggle).removeClass('active');
    });
}
else {
    $('.slide-container').slideDown(400);
    $(slideToggle).addClass('active');
}
```

});

The same goes for the [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

Theres a whole load of [easing functions](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html)

Comment: I tried what you suggested by adding the jQuery UI script and adding `easeIn` and `easeOut` to those two lines; however, now the slide doesn't slide back up when the toggle or close buttons are clicked.